# Erlang flymake with nested folders in src cannot find includes folder

Tags: emacs, erlang

Sorry for my poor English.

I'm configuring my emacs with erlang flymake. Source files in src's nested folders report 'can't find include file', but files in `src/`folder can find the include file.

My emacs settings for erlang:

```
;; erlang-mode
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B02/lib/erlang/lib/tools-2.6.8/emacs" load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B02/lib/erlang")
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B02/lib/erlang/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)

;; distel
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/distel/elisp/")
(require 'distel)
(distel-setup)

;; erlang-flymake
(require 'erlang-flymake)
(erlang-flymake-only-on-save)
```

My erlang application folder is like following:

```
app/src/      (source code)
    src/mod
    src/lib

app/include/  (hrls)
app/ebin/     (compiled code)

...etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `erlang-flymake` there are 2 variables (`erlang-flymake-get-include-dirs-function` and `erlang-flymake-get-code-path-dirs-function`), that specify functions to search include & ebin directories. Right now, they're pointing to the functions `erlang-flymake-get-include-dirs` and `erlang-flymake-get-code-path-dirs` that simply return current dir + `include` and `ebin` correspondingly. For example, you can use following code to do this:

```
(defun get-erlang-app-dir ()
  (let* ((src-path (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
     (pos (string-match "/src/" src-path)))
    (if pos
    (substring src-path 0 (+ 1 pos))
      src-path)))

(setq erlang-flymake-get-code-path-dirs-function
      (lambda ()
    (concat (get-erlang-app-dir) "ebin")))

(setq erlang-flymake-get-code-include-dirs-function
      (lambda ()
    (concat (get-erlang-app-dir) "include")))
```

P.S. Are you using rebar to maintain your project?

Comment: Thank you, let me try it. No, as this application is a legacy project, not using rebar now. Maybe I will change it to use rebar in a few weeks.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. I think `get-erlang-app-dir` is wrong. For example, there is a file '~/game/src/mod/mod_player.erl', when edit it, the app-dir should be `~/game`. But it remains ~/game/src/

Comment: It works. I just use your `get-erlang-app-dir`, let `code-path-dirs` and `code-include-dirs` as default, and it works right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello, `C-c C-k` seems cannot work. Where can I set its `include` option?

Comment: C-c C-k calls `erlang-compile-function` to obtain compilation string, so you can re-define it

Answer (score 1):

If you use erlang-flymake you might want to look at https://github.com/ten0s/syntaxerl. It's a syntax checker for Erlang. It uses erlang-flymake under the hood, but instead of `erlc' it uses a custom syntax checker that can evaluate .erl, .hrl, .config, .rel, .app, .app.src, .escript files. The syntax checker is rebar aware, but also works with standard Erlang/OTP directory structure. Emacs's setup is also there.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'll clone it and make a try.